How to run sp_blitz against all sql servers and store the output in a single table?
You can run sp_blitz (First Responder Kit by Brent Ozar) on a sql server to output to a table. But it will store the output only on that server.  I am  using Dbatools.io PowerShell commands currently. I can run the sp_Blitz commands agains all SQL servers. But I don’t know how to capture the output on my report server in a single database table centrally. Is there a way to store output of sp_blitz command against a list of all servers so that I can create a report for all critical issues across all my servers? Here is the code I am using.
Import-Module dbatools

# Set your database connection details
$database = "<Database Name>"
$table = "<table name containing server names>"
$output = "dbo.BlitzResults"
$sqlInstance = "<InstanceName>"  # The instance where the ServerList table is located

$servers = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $sqlInstance -Database $database -Query "select * from $table;"
$servers

# Loop through each server and execute sp_Blitz
foreach ($server in $servers.ItemArray) {
    Write-Host "Running sp_Blitz on $($server)"

    try {
        $result = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $server -Database master -Query "EXEC dbo.sp_Blitz"        
        # Output the results
        $result | Format-Table -AutoSize
        #Following two lines are not working as expected
        #Write-Host $result.ItemArray
        #Write-DbaDbTableData -SqlInstance $sqlInstance -DestinationDatabase $database -DestinationTable $output -Data $result.ItemArray -CreateTable $true
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to run sp_Blitz on $($server.ServerName). Error: $_"
    }
}


Short answer
You can use the @OutputServerName parameter to send the results to the SQL instance of your choice, via a Linked Server.
Long answer
Straight from Brent's mouth, at sp_Blitz Pro Tips for Managing Multiple Servers Centrally:

How to Centralize Results Across Your Estate
As long as you’re centralizing your management of checks to skip, you can also centralize the results. sp_Blitz has parameters to write the output to a database, and it works across linked servers, too:

sp_Blitz 
  @SkipChecksServer = 'ManagementServerName',
  @SkipChecksDatabase = 'DBAtools', 
  @SkipChecksSchema = 'dbo', 
  @SkipChecksTable = 'BlitzChecksToSkip',
  @OutputServerName = 'ManagementServerName',
  @OutputDatabaseName = 'DBAtools',
  @OutputSchemaName = 'dbo',
  @OutputTableName = 'BlitzResults';


sp_Blitz will create the table if it doesn’t already exist (but the linked server, database, and schema have to already exist.)
Set that up in a daily Agent job or run it centrally from PowerShell, and you can have all your servers phoning home into one table on a regular basis. You can query the results to slice & dice ’em by priority, or find out what problems are new in your environment today as opposed to yesterday.
The output table has the same results as sp_Blitz, but adds two columns: ServerName and CheckDate, so you can query data by server or by most recent check dates.


I have added a code I am using. I don't know how to store results centrally in a different database for all servers so that I can see which servers need my attention.

Brent's article steps you through it. Can you be more specific about what part is giving you trouble?

Interesting. I didn’t check the code of sp_Blitz to realize there is a parameter to store output on a central server. This is a good lead. Let me give it a shot and report back. Thank you.

It seems like this solution will require me to create a Linked Server on all the other servers as I see this error. Could not find server in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
The specified output server was not found

Yes. As the article says -- "the linked server, database, and schema have to already exist".
